# Servo creates a constant "angle error" depending on its original position

Tags: pwm, servo, error

I am trying to set a servo to move to the same angle always when given the same PWM signal. I am using a [Savox SH-0262MG](https://www.savoxusa.com/products/savsh0262mg-super-speed-metal-gear-micro). I have an issue when I first move it manually (with my hand) to one of its "ends", the "top end" lets call it, and then send the PWM signal, it moves to a angle A degrees, but if I first move it manualy to its other end, the "bottom-end", it will move to another angle (A+10) degrees.

More specifically with pictures:

When I move the servo with my hand and initialize it at bottom-end of its moving capability like this:

[image: servo manual setting]

Then I send a PWM pulse to move it at a specific angle, it moves to this bottom angle:

[image: servo move vertical]

(vertical to itself, this is what I want)

Now, if I move the servo with my hand and initialize it at the top-end of its moving capability like this:

[image: servo manual set at its end]

then send the same PWM signal as before to move it at the same angle, it moves a bit off like this:

[image: servo moves a bit off after manual set]

Moving it to the top-end will give the servo a constant "error" for the rest of its movements (that is, for every PWM pulse I send.) It does not matter how long the PWM pulse lasts, if I reset the MCU, or re-power the board/servo, it will have this constant angle error. This constant +10 degree "wrong angle" persists, and only gets fixed if I move the servo manually to the bottom-end by hand.

The angle where it will move depends on the original angle that I set it to manually, and this creates a "mechanical error" lets call it, since it can be fixed only if I move the servo manually to its other end.

1. Is this mechanical constant error common with all servos?
2. Is this error due to the lack of feedback servos have? (I suspect this is what it is.)
3. What is this  "mechanical constant error" actually called so I can google it, maybe find a solution?
4. Is there any case this error fixing itself as time passes (while it is being used?) This would be bad for me as I want it to move to the points I originally set it to in the laboratory.

Comment: You are probably forcing the position against its will so it might have a friction clutch that slips in order for you to do that. Simple solution, don’t do that.

Comment: Hm, so when I get the servo on my hands, I just don't move it with my hand to its ends? Sounds good enough for me, and a logical explanation as well.

Comment: If you need to know its position you may need to calibrate it at power-on, e.g. by operating over full range and checking both end positions (either visually, or with sensors or microswitches).

Comment: The error you are getting is way outside the acceptable amount for any RC servo, so either the servo is faulty or you are doing something wrong. Are you sending PWM pulses continuously, or just sending one pulse and expecting the arm to move to the desired position and hold it?

Comment: @BruceAbbott sending one specific PWM pulse, continuously.

Comment: RC servos do not have 'friction clutches'. It should go to the same angle (within 1~2º) when the PWM pulse is the same, even if it has been manually moved to another position (which you should never force it to when active, for risk of breaking gears etc.). So the possibilities are:- 1. the horn is slipping on the shaft (wrong horn, stripped spline?). The servo pulse is not stable. 3. The servo is faulty (broken gear teeth, feedback pot slipping on output shaft, motor driver partially burned out etc.).

Comment: I see that you manually moved the arm to its extremes of travel (~220º?) far beyond the normal range of 90º. What happens if you only move it +-45º off center? When the servo is active, does it strongly resist any attempt to manually move it in either direction?

Comment: http://heli-heli.com/items/servos/savox/helicopter/savox-sh-0262mg-super-speed-metal-gear-micro-digital-servo-savsh0262mg-savsh0262mg-detail.htm